# Tag synonym: [inverse-matrix] and [matrix-inverse]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Although not sharing exactly the same meaning, it would seems that having [inverse-matrix](/questions/tagged/inverse-matrix) and [matrix-inverse](/questions/tagged/matrix-inverse) as not-synonyms will be more confusing them having them as synonym.

Can anyone help out here?

I do not have enough rep/score to propose this synonym in the conventional channels, I was hoping to get some assistance here.

**EDIT:**
I see that a while ago [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) acted on this issue and [proposed the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matrix-inverse/synonyms). Thank you!

### Kind request:

If anyone sees this post and have enough rep and score - please go and upvote this synonym!

Comment: I'm not a professional mathematician but it seems _matrix inverse_ and _inverse matrix_ are interchangeable terms with neither being more correct, so either could become the synonym of the other. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse) uses both interchangeably. Wolfram MathWorld has [Inverse Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseMatrix.html) redirect to Matrix Inverse. Math.SE uses [both](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22matrix+inverse%22) [terms](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22inverse+matrix%22), with "inverse matrix" being more popular.

Comment: @Shai: ah the dreaded issue of tag synonyms. I find it ridiculous that with enough reputation, you can create any new tag you want but you still cannot suggest/upvote synonyms as you like. The issue is some tags are a niche area, and its very hard to get to that minimum threshold that qualifies you to upvote synonyms. Btw I just stumbled onto this, so you welcome :) (you dont get "Inbox notifications" with '@<USER>' unless you participate in the thread)